# Centering the application launchers on the panel in 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, icons

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with the default Unity desktop environment on a Lenovo Yoga 3 pro.

I have moved my launcher panel to the bottom of my screen, from the left, and have it so that it auto hides. I'm now wondering if it is possible to have the icons centre align rather than left align. Has anybody else tried and succeeded in doing this and if so could you share the process and commands?

Comment: For clarity, i'm not looking for a solution like Plank or Cairo Dock which I've used in the past and work wonderfully, but rather a native way of achieving a similar affect.

Comment: Did you try playing around with `compizconfig-settings-manager` ?

Comment: @Ziazis, Not yet. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Just looked a little into the settings available from the tweak-unity and compiz stuff. I think there is no option for centering the apps. At least I couldn't find one ;/

Comment: Yes, that's because it is not a dock. It is a Launcher and way different from a dock. This is what Canonical has to say. So, there is no native way for achieving it.

Comment: AFAIK this is not implemented in the code so there's no settings that you can change to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is not available in the unity code and as unity is being retired as the default desktop environment it's not likely that development efforts will go into providing a centering option for icons in the launcher under unity. I reccommed that you revert to the solutions that you've used in the past such as [`cairo-dock`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=+cairo-dock+&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)or perhaps [docky](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/docky) both of these are currently available in the universe repository for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, or [`plank`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=plank) which also available in the universe repository (for 16.04 and newer versions of Ubuntu).